# Check if data exists in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a checking from my table. I have three tables `hari` , `transaksi` & `Outlet`.

My table `hari` has only one column called `days`:

```
              days
    2016-07-21 00:00:00.000
    2016-07-22 00:00:00.000
    2016-07-23 00:00:00.000
    2016-07-24 00:00:00.000
    2016-07-25 00:00:00.000
    2016-07-26 00:00:00.000
```

My second table is `transaksi`:

```
| outlet     | Tanggal |
  K-MGAS      2016-07-23 
  K-JGMM2     2016-07-24 
  K-JGMM2     2016-07-25  
  K-CL4       2016-07-26
```

and the last one is `outlet`:

```
   | OutletCode |
       K-MGAS
       K-JGMM2
       K-CL4
```

As you can see days and `outlet` is master table and transaksi is transaction table. Now, I have a problem when I try to select an outlet which does not have any transactions.

My desired result is like this

```
| Outlet |         Days          |
  K-MGAS  2016-07-21 00:00:00.000
  K-MGAS  2016-07-22 00:00:00.000
  K-MGAS  2016-07-24 00:00:00.000
  K-MGAS  2016-07-25 00:00:00.000
  K-MGAS  2016-07-26 00:00:00.000
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `Now, i have a problem when i try to select an outlet which not have transaction` - What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cross join and then Left join

```
SELECT O.OutletCode
       ,H.Days
FROM Outlet O
CROSS JOIN Hari H
LEFT JOIN Transaksi T ON T.Outlet = O.OutletCode
    AND T.Days = H.Days
WHERE T.Days IS NULL
```

Comment: it's my first time using `cross join` and it's working with charm

Comment: but why this ? `WHERE T.Days IS NULL`

Comment: @YVS1102 Because if left join doesn't find data on Transaksi T.Days will be null and that's what you were looking for

Comment: @YVS1102 Cross Join will work fine here, but be carefull if you have many records on Hari, you might want to select just a certain amount of days

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT O.*
  FROM Outlet O
 LEFT JOIN Transaksi T ON T.Outlet = O.OutletCode
 WHERE T.Days IS NULL
```

Comment: Hmm, it just like my query now.

Comment: my bad. because i hate to put my full table here, inside my question i using fake field name

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking something similar to following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Outlet O
CROSS JOIN Hari H
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Transaksi WHERE Outlet=O.OutletCode AND Tanggal=H.Days)
```